# Flash Key-Frames

Tags: flash

In Flash (AC3) I am able to leave key-frame 2 and land on key-frame 6 and return to key-frame 2 what I want to do is leave any frame land on 6 and return to the frame I left?

Comment: What i have tried so far        btn4.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_MouseClickHandler1);

function fl_MouseClickHandler1(event:MouseEvent):void
 {
      if (textbox2.text.indexOf("ball") != -1) {
          gotoAndStop("correct");
      } else {
         gotoAndStop("wrong");
      }
   }

Answer (score 0):

```
private var frameILeft:int;

private function jumpToFrame6():void{
    frameILeft = currentFrame;
    gotoAndStop(6);
}
```

to go to frame 6:   jumpToFrame6().
then go back:       gotoAndStop(frameILeft).